# JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None when scraping

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to take the data in json from this page https://www.era.co.za/property/for-sale, however I am getting the type Error. Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
import json
import requests
from pprint import pprint


#requests.get('https://www.era.co.za/property/for-sale').json()
class EraSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'era'
    start_urls = ['https://www.era.co.za/property/for-sale']

    def parse(self, response):
        results = json.loads(response.body)
        pprint(results)
```

When I run `print(requests.get('https://www.era.co.za/property/for-sale').content)`, I am able to see the content but when trying to load it as json I get the error. Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try `pprint(response.body)`, see if the response has unexpected content.

Comment: @Gallaecio it seems like there are bunch of random letters before the actual data. Do you perhaps know how can I go around that?

Comment: request to this url ```https://www.era.co.za/property/for-sale``` never returns JSON, it returns HTML. if you saw part of JSON inside content, then first of all you need to find that element (by xpath or css) that contains json data and than use it.

Answer (score 0):

as @Roman allready mentioned in the comments, the url "https://www.era.co.za/property/for-sale" always retuns `HTML`, and not `JSON`.

If you want to get values inside it, you'll need to find the Element, for example by `Element-id`, `XPATH`, `css`, `class` or others.